# How to install bzip2 for Capistrano-db-tasks on Windows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, bzip2

I had an error with installation of **bzip2 on Windows 7 for capistrano-db-tasks**. I tried gem bzip2, gem bzip2-ruby and gem bzip2-ruby-rb20.

How to install it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need to install bzip2 libs. Download **zipped** libs from [Bzip2 for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/bzip2.htm), Binaries. Unpack them to directory without spaces, say C:\GnuWin32\bzip2-1.0.5-bin. lib subdir should contain libbz2.a, libbz2.def, libbz2.dll.a. This path (C:\GnuWin32\bzip2-1.0.5-bin\lib) should be provided to --with-bz2-lib.

2) The package bzip2-ruby seems to have a not-fixed error yet according to the author [github.com/brianmario](https://github.com/brianmario/bzip2-ruby/issues/19%29) (version.h is absent). So you can install bzip2-ruby-rb20 as he suggests.

```
gem install bzip2-ruby-rb20 -- --with-bz2-include="C:\GnuWin32\bzip2-1.0.5-bin\include" -- --with-bz2-lib="C:\GnuWin32\bzip2-1.0.5-bin\lib"
```

Should be done.
Now you can use commands as "cap db:pull".

[Thx to [this post]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21853821/3324219)